# Symfony REST API - how to handle invalid form

Tags: angular, forms, rest, symfony, symfony4

Symfony 4 as a backend, Angular as frontend. I have a simple form - let's say two fields which cannot be blank.

Entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="signature", type="string", length=32, unique=true)
 * @JMSSerializer\Expose
 */
private $signature;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
 * @JMSSerializer\Expose
 */
private $status;
```

So default is NOT NULL.

After leaving one of those fields blank and submitting the form I get 500 error. Dev.log says: "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot be null". Obviously. But how to catch this error? Or maybe just prevent submitting a form with blank fields on Angular side?

My controller:

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('App\Form\ItemType', null, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if (!$form->isValid()) {            
        return $form;
    }
    ...
```

As suggested elsewhere I could send an array of errors:

```
$errors = [];
foreach ($form->getErrors(true) as $error) {
    if ($error->getOrigin()) {
        $errors[$error->getOrigin()->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But isValid() method is never called.

BTW) Is it a good idea to return a form as a response in this case? I have seen this in some tutorial. But maybe returning

```
new View(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
```

with some additional info would be a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Tompo if you want to use form for validation you need to do like this in your entity

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="signature", type="string", length=32, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a signature")
 * @JMSSerializer\Expose
 */
private $signature;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter a status")
 * @JMSSerializer\Expose
 */
private $status;
```

Now you can get call if fileds are blank, after this you need to edit your controller for display errors messages

Comment: Thats it! I had no idea this applies also to rest api.